# Nginx Proxy Pass SSL Verification

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I am using proxy_pass directive to upstream https server. The proxy server is meant for LAN clients. The upstream https server uses letsencrypt. How do I configure SSL verification?

```
proxy_pass https://upstream.backend
proxy_verify_ssl on;
proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate <which_file_is_supposed_to_be_here>;
proxy_ssl_verify_depth <what_number_here>;
```

Comment: Welcome to [sf]. I've removed your second unrelated question, as our Q&A format only permits one question per "question". Please feel free to research it separately and [post a new question](/questions/ask) if you haven't already found an answer for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation for `proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate`](https://nginx.org/r/proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate) states:

> Specifies a `file` with trusted CA certificates in the PEM format used to [verify](https://nginx.org/r/proxy_ssl_verify) the certificate of the proxied HTTPS server.

Since you're validating public TLS certificates, you can point it at your system's CA certificate bundle. By default on Red Hat derived systems this is `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` or `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.trust.crt`. Your location may vary if you for some reason don't use a Red Hat derived system as your web server.

If you want, you can also download Let's Encrypt's CA certificate separately, place that on your filesystem somewhere, and point at it.

Comment: For some reason I couldn't decipher, pointing to the downloaded certificate wouldn't work for me. Pointing to the system CA cert file works... Thanks